# Show Query Results in Month/Year Order

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a query that sales and it shows the month and year (field names are salemonth & saleyear) of the sale.  Example return-set would be

```
January 2014
February 2014
March 2014
December 2014
January 2015
```

Now obviously I can't set it that way in my straight query as if I try to order by salemonth ASC it woudl show December, February, january, january, March.  or even if I order by year ASC it still would not show in the actual calendar month order.  How can I sort this result set to show in the order of an actual calendar?

One caveat their may be 0 sales for the month (november for example) I would still want this month/year shown in the query but have a 0 shown.  Is this achievable?

Comment: You seem to be trying to solve two different problems...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick idea and fix (not the prettiest of solutions):

```
SELECT *, CAST(([Month] + ' 1,' + [Year]) AS Datetime) AS OrderDate FROM [TABLE] ORDER BY OrderDate
```

..or if you prefer to hide the sorting column:

```
SELECT * FROM [TABLE] ORDER BY CAST(([Month] + ' 1,' + [Year]) AS Datetime)
```

This is assuming the values are stored as some type of varchar/string, otherwise you'd obviously need to cast a few more bits.

Comment: ah-hah!  I didn't think of combining the 2 columns as 1 then ordering by the "New" column.  Thank you!!!!